# Sitecore 6.4 - publishing clones

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

From my understanding of how cloning works, when a change to a parent of a clone is published to the web database that change should be immediately apparent for the clone as well, as the clone fields merely reference the fields of the parent.

However, while I can see changes immediately in clones in the content tree (already on the save event) publishing the parent doesn't seem to affect the clone in the web database - old values are maintained - at least temporarily. Publishing the clone will push the change to the clone on the web.

Incremental publish of entire site didn't force update.

Viewing the clone in the content tree in the web database showed the clone with old data (unsurprisingly).

Saving the clone, then incrementally publishing did force the update to the clone on the web.

From all of this I surmise that what actually happens with clones is that their data is read into the web database when the clones themselves are saved/published, rather than that they are truly just reference pointers. Though the master database clones are apparently functioning as references.

This would seem to allow for a fair amount of flexibility, and the functionality I'd like to see could feasibly be built on top of this - that when a parent of a clone is updated an owner of the clone receives a notification and can choose whether to accept the update. This notification is currently only possible when the clone owner has overwritten a field.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Edit: cross posted to SDN forum, no response there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some semi-official information regarding clones and publishing and also regarding cross-database clones (which aren't supported, yet).

**Regarding publishing:**

> Publishing converts cloned data to field values.

**Regarding cross-database clones:**

> The Sitecore 6.4 UI does not support cross-database clones, but this seems inevitable.

ref: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/10/Sitecore-CMS-6-4-Cloning.aspx

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'd read that article ages ago, but obviously glanced over that particular bit! Still waiting for some clearer official documentation though. And still waiting for some sort of recommendation about internal links in cloned sections of sites.